# How to parse the results of testng-results.xml file generated

Tags: testng

How can I get the results summary from the  testng-results.xml file i.e no. of test cases  : passed, failed ..
it will be easy if I can get a java code or tool to that.
My input is testng-results.xml file and required o/p is summary of all the test cases: failed, passed , skipped.
Thanks in advance!!
Vivek Pemawat

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/test-output/testng-results.xml";

    File fXmlFile = new File(path);

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    System.out.println("Total : " + doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("total")) ;
    System.out.println("Passed : " +doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("passed")) ;
    System.out.println("Failed : " +doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("failed")) ;
    System.out.println("Skipped : " +doc.getDocumentElement().getAttribute("skipped")) ;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without parsing? By creating Java objects that will map directly to the XML? I couldnt find the DTD schema definition to create the Java classes automatically.